# What is the AngularJS bootstrap process in detail?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It'd be really helpful to have insight into the AngularJS bootstrap process. When does it first load and what events get called and in what order?

I've come across the traditional -

- config
- run
- compile
- controller
- link

...explanation, but this is a little too abstract for me.

Is there a more well-defined/explained bootstrap process for AngularJS? Preferably I'd like to get an example that includes the injector, and how modules, services, etc. are executed and in what order. I just haven't seen anything like this and I think it'd be a tremendous help to see it.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)? Perhaps you could ask a more specific question for your particular need.

Comment: I'd like to see a manual bootstrap process. Is there an example someplace out there? The documentation at Angular is terse and difficult to read.

Comment: If all you need to do is to manually bootstrap, then the documentation has a very simple example. You seem to be looking for something else, so can you add the context of what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I was searching for a more detailed oriented example where Angular was manually boostrapped that would include the ng-app directive (which the documentation provides) all the way to the instantiating of controllers/services/etc. I've seen examples of controllers being instantiated w/the injector manually.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information [straight from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) on how Angular starts up.

```
Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js 
script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'. At this 
point Angular looks for the ng-app directive which designates your application root. 
If the ng-app directive is found then Angular will:

 - load the module associated with the directive.
 - create the application injector
 - compile the DOM treating the ng-app directive as the root of the
   compilation. This allows you to tell it to treat only a portion of
   the DOM as an Angular application.
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit subjective Matthew, but the above is still very abstract. I was hoping to get help w/more specifics. I find the documentation at the Angular homepage to be incredible terse and difficult to understand.

Comment: @CharlesSounder I think you might get better answers if you are able to define what is too abstract or terse about the docs own definition. Without that, this is probably one of the best descriptions that I've come across.